# Intercept sending request to change a header with request library

Tags: node.js, request, multipartform-data

I am using the infamous [request library](https://github.com/request/request) to send requests.
One of those requests requires me to send the header `multipart/mixed; boundary={myboundary}`.

Request is using the [form-data library](https://github.com/form-data/form-data) for such requests but it does not set the `Content-Type` header properly. Therefore I would need to set it like this:

```
let req = request.post({url: "https://..."}, formData: formData)
req.setHeader('Content-Type', `multipart/mixed; boundary=${req.form().getBoundary()}`)
```

Sadly I can't add/alter any headers after firing the request. Therefore I want to know whether there is a way to intercept the sending so I can change the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [`multipart` option](https://github.com/request/request#multipartrelated) instead of `formData` to use other, arbitrary `multipart/*` content types. Each object in the `multipart` array contains the headers to send in that part. The one exception is the `body` property which is used as the actual body of that part.

```
request.post({
  url: 'https://...',
  multipart: [
    { 'X-Foo-Header': 'bar', body: 'baz' },
    // ...
  ],
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed' }
});
```

The boundary should be automatically appended for an existing, explicit `Content-Type` header. [This `request` test](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/tests/test-multipart.js) explicitly tests for this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for looking it up. I still get a status code 415 when doing it as you suggested.

Comment: So it seems it only works with the `multipart` API then. I've updated the example and tested it locally.